# Delphi collision detection issues with more than one object

Tags: delphi, collision-detection

For some reason my collision code isn't working with more than one object. It works perfectly with one but when I try to do it with another object at the same time it fails and the player can move through each object. I plan to create the objects in a dynamic array and loop through this code for each object but it has the same issue as there is some problem with running the code twice that breaks all the collision detection?

Full project paste bin with 1 object working:
https://pastebin.com/MgEdbE4N
Full project paste bin with 2 objects not working:
https://pastebin.com/D3dpyxxD

On timer procedure with collision detection code for both objects copied twice:

```
        procedure TForm1.OnTick(Sender: TObject);
      var IntersectionRect: TRect;
    begin
    //First object
      if not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape1.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape1.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
        begin
          if d = true then
          Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
        end;
      if not((Image1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.Y >= Shape1.Top - 10) and (Image1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.Y <= Shape1.Top + 10) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
       begin
         if s = true then
          Image1.Top := Image1.Top + 5;
       end;
      if not((Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.X - 10 <= (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width)) and (Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.X + 10 >= (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width))  and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
      begin
        if a = true then
        Image1.Left := Image1.Left - 5;
      end;
     if not((Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.Y <= Shape1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.y + 10) and (Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.Y >= Shape1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.y - 10) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
      begin
        if w = true then
        Image1.Top := Image1.Top - 5;
      end;


    //second object
       if not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape2.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape2.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect)) then
        begin
          if d = true then
          Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
        end;
      if not((Image1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.Y >= Shape2.Top - 10) and (Image1.BoundsRect.BottomRight.Y <= Shape2.Top + 10) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect)) then
       begin
         if s = true then
          Image1.Top := Image1.Top + 5;
       end;
      if not((Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.X - 10 <= (Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width)) and (Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.X + 10 >= (Shape2.Left + Shape1.Width))  and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect)) then
      begin
        if a = true then
        Image1.Left := Image1.Left - 5;
      end;
     if not((Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.Y <= Shape2.BoundsRect.BottomRight.y + 10) and (Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.Y >= Shape2.BoundsRect.BottomRight.y - 10) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect)) then
      begin
        if w = true then
        Image1.Top := Image1.Top - 5;
      end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively your code says "If A collides does not collide with B **OR** A does not collide with C then move" What you need is the opposite "If A does not collide with B **AND** A does not collide with C then move", e.g.

```
// both objects
      if (not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape1.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape1.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect))
      and (not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape2.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape2.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect)) ) then
        begin
          if d = true then
          Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
        end;
```

and similarly for your other tests.

Obviously we are merging the 2 blocks so there should only be one block when you are done.

### Edit 1

Obviously this is not suitable for multiple shapes - it just shows you why what you are doing does not work. You need to refactor.

Look at this an example of what you need to do:

```
if not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape1.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape1.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
        begin
          if d = true then
          Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
        end;
```

This is both testing for collision if we move, then if our direction is down, we move. Well we are doing the complicated test first then the simple bit. Both must be true so the first stage is reverse the order

```
        if d = true then
          if not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape1.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape1.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then
          begin
            Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
          end;
```

But this is still doing the collision test and move together, so we separate out

```
function CollideD( Image1 : TImage Shape1Rect : TShape );  // or as appropriate
begin
              if not(((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) >= Shape1.Left-10 ) and ((Image1.Width + Image1.BoundsRect.TopLeft.x) <= Shape1.Left+10 ) and IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Image1.BoundsRect, Shape1.BoundsRect)) then Result := FALSE else Result := TRUE; 

end;

procedure MoveD( Iamge1 : TImage );
begin
     Image1.Left := Image1.Left + 5;
end;

...

  if d = true then
   if not CollideD( Image1, Shape1 ) then 
   begin
     MoveD( Image1 );
   end;
```

OK, now we have separated collision detect and movement for d, multiple shapes becomes easy

Something like

```
var
  iCanMove : Boolean;

...

   iCanMove := TRUE;
   if d then
   begin

     for I := 0 to ShapeList.Count - 1 do
     begin
       if CollideD( Image1, ShapeList[ I ] ) then
       begin
         iCanMove : FALSE;
         break; 
       end;
     end;
     if iCanMove then MoveD( Image1 );
   end;
```

Now all of this is untested - I am just aiming to show you how to proceed - I am not going to write your code for you. Plus you need to repeat for s, w and a.

But hopefully you can see the value of structuring your code properly now.

Comment: This works thanks but how could you alter it to work for an array of objects? As you cant add another AND statement to all the IF statements every time you want it to work with a new object.

Comment: Your code is designed for 'efficient and fast operation' not for robustness and ease of maintenance. You need to seriously refactor it, splitting out the functionality of collision detect and moving. That will slow the code down of course, but there are certain optimisations to make it run faster, such as breaking out of  the collision detect loop when a collision is detected. Once you have separated the functionality, expanding to an arbitrary number of shapes becomes child's play. Plus your code becomes more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: And to be fair, cutting and pasting blocks isn't really an option either.

Comment: Also I would invert the logic - using s, d, a and w to determine which collision detection is used, not determine if there is a collision and then decide if we can move. There is a lot wrong with how you are doing things.

Comment: Honestly I cannot see how to use the if statement with an array because I cant add an infinite amount of if statements for every shape in my array. Example: https://pastebin.com/FbUkDc8Z

Comment: No, you can't. That is why you need to refactor. I will edit to show you how to do it in one case.